# Why won't API pull proper data?

Tags: python, api

I need to pull data from an API.

When I run my Python code, it returns a long HTML string when I need standard data like this:

Date    Time    Country     City    Device  Scans
06/16/2020  3:41 PM     US  Watertown   AndroidOS   1
06/16/2020  1:26 PM     US  Watertown   AndroidOS   1

Here is my code:

```
import requests


url = "https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/campaign/6RG-UQQ"

querystring = {"page": 1, "limit": 5, "sort": 1}

headers = {
    'x-qrtiger-host': "qrtiger.com",
    'x-qrtiger-key': "Bearer xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)

f = open('/home/person/Documents/newfile.csv', "w")
f.write(response.text)
f.close()
```

It works with other APIs. I checked the documentation for this API at https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/api and the "Consume API" button sends me to a bad link. Any way around this or am I screwed? Note: the file path is different because I am using Linux; It works on my machine.

Comment: The html page that is being returned my contain the error message you are getting. May be bad parameters or something

Comment: Thanks, I spoke to the developers, and it looks like they can get it it run. I still cannot. The documentation is very unclear.